# Could not download gem 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Jekyll site, I'm unable to successfully `bundle install` with this error:

```
Bundler::HTTPError: Could not download gem from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <bad response Forbidden 403
(https://rubygems.org/gems/sass-embedded-1.69.5-x86_64-linux.gem)>
```

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, but it does seem like that URL doesn't exist. It looks like there should be a suffix, like `-gnu`. But I'm not sure how to work around this. Here's my Gemfile if it helps:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

gemspec

group :test do
  gem "html-proofer", "~> 4.4"
end

# Windows and JRuby does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# and associated library.
platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem "tzinfo", ">= 1", "< 3"
  gem "tzinfo-data"
end

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

# Lock `http_parser.rb` gem to `v0.6.x` on JRuby builds since newer versions of the gem
# do not have a Java counterpart.
gem "http_parser.rb", "~> 0.6.0", :platforms => [:jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and changed the following.

from

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux-musl/
  gem "jekyll-sass-converter", "~> 2.0"
end
```

to

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux-gnu/
  gem "jekyll-sass-converter", "~> 2.0"
end
```

and now I can update again.